# Abort Trap: 6 bash / cd

Tags: bash

After cd'ing I get the error "Abort Trap: 6". This continues after every command from then on.

Bash version: GNU bash, version 4.4.0(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin16.0.0)

**Update**

problem persist after reboot, logging out / in, and spawning a new shell

.bash_profile

```
#[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
##
# Your previous /Users/austin/.bash_profile file was backed up as /Users/austin/.bash_profile.macports-saved_2015-11-19_at_16:17:31
##
export PATH="/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH"

source /Users/austin/git_projects/biohitech-bash-tools/bash_profile
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
   source ~/.bashrc
fi
```

~/.bashrc

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
source /Users/austin/git_projects/bash_profile/profile
```

Sourced files in .bash_profile

```
export PS1='\033[1;0;32m \033[38;5;220m\033[1;0;32m> \e[0m'
# export PS1='\[\033[1;0;32m\][ \W\[\033[38;5;220m\]\[\033[1;0;32m\]]$ \[\e[0m\]'
#####################################
############# Functions #############
#####################################
function exiled() {
    for f in *.mkv
    do
        mv $f  `echo $f | sed 's/.Exiled-Destiny._//g' | sed -E 's/_(\()[a-zA-Z0-9]+(\))//g'`
    done
}

function uploadImage {
    ext=$1

    if [ "$ext" == "help" ]; then
    printf "Description:\n\tUploads all images in directory of extension type specified to imgur.com\nExample:\n\tuploadImage jpg\nFile Types:\n\tPEG, PNG, GIF, APNG, TIFF, BMP, PDF, XCF (GIMP). Please note that TIFF, BMP, PDF and XCF (GIMP) will be converted to PNG on upload. PNGs over 756KB are automatically converted to JPG.\n\n\tImgur does not currently support WEBM, MP4, or GIFV uploads. They will need     to be converted before upload.\n"
    else
        for f in *".$1";
        do
            printf "$f\t"
            curl -s -F "image=@$f" -F "key=26ff5c40cbedf50e7f81124ab473c1cc" https://imgur.com/api/upload.xml | grep -E -o "<original_image>(.)*</original_image>" | grep -E -o "http://i.imgur.com/[^<]*"
        done
    fi
}


######################################
############## Aliases ###############
######################################
alias cls=clear
alias ls="ls -AGh"
alias grep="grep --color"
alias serve="python -m SimpleHTTPServer"
alias _=sudo
alias ytmp3="youtube-dl --extract-audio --audio-format mp3"
alias pgoff='brew services stop postgresql'
alias pgon='brew services start postgresql'
eval "$(thefuck --alias)"


# nginx
alias ngon="brew services start nginx"
alias ngoff="brew services stop nginx"
alias ngrestart="brew services restart nginx"

#####################################
############## Exports ##############
#####################################
export LSCOLORS=gxBxhxDxfxhxhxhxhxcxcx
export PATH="~/Downloads/:$PATH"


####################################
############## Misc ################
####################################

####################################
#           Completion             #
####################################

# Git
if [[ -f completions/git.bash ]]; then
    source ./completions/git.bash
fi

# npm
if [[ -f completions/npm.bash ]]; then
    source ./completions/npm.bash
fi


#####################################
############# z command #############
#####################################
if command -v brew >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    # Load rupa's z if installed
    [ -f $(brew --prefix)/etc/profile.d/z.sh ] && source $(brew --prefix)/etc/profile.d/z.sh
fi
```

Output from printf '%s\n' "$PROMPT_COMMAND"

```
update_terminal_cwd
_z --add "$(command pwd -P 2>/dev/null)" 2>/dev/null;
```

**Update 2**

The problems seems to start when cd'ing to folders owned by users who are not myself.

ex `cd /Users/testuser` or `cd /var/log`

Any help would be great.

Comment: Interesting.  Some questions (please [edit details into your post](http://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/258032/edit), don't respond in comments): Does it still occur if you log out and log in (or better yet, restart your computer)?  If you type `bash` to spawn a new shell (probably with a different prompt), does it occur in the new shell?  What is the contents of your `~/.bashrc` and/or `~/.bash_profile`?  What is the output of `printf '%s\n' "$PROMPT_COMMAND"`?

Comment: Does the problem persist if you unset `PROMPT_COMMAND`? What does `_z` do (in `PROMPT_COMMAND`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be caused by the z command ([found here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjaxvuptuzPAhWMcD4KHXZyDNgQFggeMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Frupa%2Fz&usg=AFQjCNHIL8v5Dy8LfMgx6Kc5td1lHswI9w)) being sourced in ~/.bash_profile

I will be reporting the bug asap.